# Blazor Desktop read/write file?

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps

I can't read nor write files from/to disk when using Blazor WASM (PWA). Blazor Server has no PWA option but can read and write from/to disk.

How am I supposed to do it in Blazor for a desktop application? I need among others to access an SQLite database file.

I converted to Blazor Server instead for now but that's not great (because no PWA and various other differences).

Comment: No SPA can access user file or use SQLite. Read up on the Browser security model.

Comment: I know. Why did Microsoft put the PWA on WASM instead of on Server? What is the intended way for Blazor desktop?

Comment: PWA would never work on the Server variety.   You have an IndexedDb built into your Browser. For Sqlite, use Blazor Server or Wasm + API server. See the Wasm Hosted template.

Comment: I saw some people hacking PWA into Blazor Server but it can't be right I guess. It's also not nice having to run 2 separate applications for a desktop app (1 PWA and 1 back-end) just to access the local file system. I'm afraid that you're right. For now, I'll just stick to Blazor Server and no PWA then.

Answer (score 1):

Blazor WASM has, as others have noted, the same limitations as all other websites. Whether it is a SPA or if it is a PWA doesn't mean that it is not sandboxed.

I have been working on wrapping a browser API in Blazor called the File System Access API which adds access to the native file system. It is not supported on many browsers, but can be used for PoCs. Check out the support here: https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api

You can check out my wrapper of the API here: https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.FileSystemAccess

And you can check out some demos of using it here: https://kristofferstrube.github.io/Blazor.FileSystemAccess/

Some have worked on using this specifically load a local SqLite database like you described. You can check that out here: https://github.com/alcedosoft/Blazor.Sqlite.FileSystemAccess